# Best way to parse user input using getline?

Tags: c++

So I need a little help with understanding the best way of getting input from the user and storing it in 2 separate data types. What I want to do is take the input example:

```
remove 44
```

I want to take the the first part "remove" and save it as a string to know which function I need to call, but then I want to take the 44 and save it as an int to be the input into said function. So far what I have is

```
string In;
getline (cin, In);
```

Now should I change the getline to delimit the space to get two strings and if so how would I go about doing that or should I just take the whole input and create 2 substrings from it?

I know this is a pretty simple problem but I don't have much experience working with user input in C++. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with stream operators? As in `cin >> In; cin >> n;`?

Comment: I have used them but not extensively. I was also under the impression getline was considered better practice. If there is a better way then I would be open to it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the operator>> to do this by doing

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    string id;
    int data;
};

istream & operator>>(istream& is, SomeStruct& someData)
{
    is >> (string&)someData.id;
    is >> someData.data;

    return is;
}
```

Then later

```
SomeStruct test;
cin >> test;
```

To learn more about the operator>>, take a look at [istream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).

To learn more about operator overloading, take a look at [C++ Operator Overloading Guidelines](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html).

Comment: Hmm that is an interesting solution but I was looking for something a little simpler as this is only for a small coding example for class, but I will definitely keep this in mind next time I am dealing with user input. Thanks.

Comment: Well you could get your "In" value and parse that, but that will be more of a "hack" and probably about as much code as this. Unless you are explicitly told to use getline, I would suggest this way. As someone who has given programming questions in the past (through lessons and interviews), I would rather see this as the response than something more rigid.

Comment: Alright I'll give this a try. I can use this in my Main.cpp right?

Comment: It can go directly into main.cpp, from your code it looks like you already have string and iostream included, so it should compile with no problem.

Comment: Everything is working now except for one thing. It will not let me simply put an input like "add" without a number. I need it to be able to also work with just a string to tell it what function to call.